# Action Message tag in struts2

Tags: struts2

I'm new to struts to How to decorate the action message and action errors in struts2 jsp page?

```
<s:actionmessage/>
<s:actionerror/>
```

Comment: You can use simple theme and you can apply your desired css styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the css styles as well as jquery theme attribute to decorate your action error and action message.

```
<div class="error"><s:actionerror theme="jquery"/></div>
<div class="message"><s:actionmessage theme="jquery"/></div>

.message li
{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000066;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS,sans-serif,inherit,Arial,monospace;
}

.error li
{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #990000;
    text-align: center; 
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi here i am posting solution for your problem if you want your action messages and error messages to decorate use this code

```
<div id="sucessMsg"><s:actionerror /></div>


sucessMsg is the class that is using by struts2 internally so override this so kindly put the below code inside the css

#sucessMsg {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color:  #6A2A91;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
}

#errorMsg {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: red;
    list-style: none;
    width: 350px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should view the HTML source after it is rendered to see the CSS classes and HTML structure that Struts uses to render the message.  You can also look in the template files.

By Default struts renders each action message as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="actionMessage">${message}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Every message will have a  `<li><span class="actionMessage">${message}</span></li>`.

You can create CSS for actionMessage or change the template file to render these however you want.

The template files for these are located in:

```
/template/simple/actionerror.ftl
/template/simple/actionmessage.ftl
```

Field Error might be useful to you as well:

```
/template/simple/fielderror.ftl
```

**note:** if you are using the xhtml theme those files *may* be located in that folder under template

Comment: It's worth remembering that in any struts2 UI tag you may add style,id and class attributes for styling purposes as well.